# what is the cons and pros of using webfiltering based on cloud security?

Tags: web-browser, proxy, cloud-computing

nowadays some vendors offering web filtering based on cloud security , where your web traffic will be forwarded to vendor cloud to be filtered and controlled at the vendor proxy , the vendor will provide you with management interface to define your own we browsing policy, comparing to having your own web proxy with web filtering capabilities , what is the cons and the pros of this solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Pros:

- Possibly reduced cost. You won't be maintaining your own
  infrastructure.
- Cloud solutions typically allow you to force company assets (like laptops for example) to      be routed through the cloud proxy for URL filtering even when off network. (increased security)

Cons:

- *Could* increase latency. This may or may not be applicable based on your location.
- Less control over the infrastructure. With an internal solution you can disperse proxies over different locations and chain them together for increase response times.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where this proxy device would hypothetically reside on your local network, it could cause unintended local congestion, interfaces errors, etc.  The cloud solution would keep all this off your network.

Answer (score -1):

Cloud-based filters offer several advantages over appliance based filters.

There is no need to purchase an appliance, so that is a big initial saving

DNS-based cloud filters are quick and easy to implement. You just point your DNS to the solution provider

There is no latency, at least with a DNS-based filter such as WebTitan

Cloud-based filters are more scalable - If you expand your operations, you don't need to purchase another appliance

Cloud-based filters can be easily accessed from anywhere via the management console - They are also great for MSPs as no site visits are needed.